# iCloud folders not appearing in the Mac Finder

Tags: icloud, finder

Really frustrating problem where files and folders in a folder synced to my iCloud were not appearing in Finder. They were still on my iCloud and when I looked into my iPad which synced these files and folders, they were all there. When I went to the terminal and entered one of the iCloud synced folders (e.g. Desktop) and did `ls -a`, the files and folders were not there.

Have restarted Mac several times, restarted finder, still no luck. How to make those files and folders synced to iCloud reappear?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, after a couple of hours of frustration, I solved my problem by: Opening Finder > Finder Preferences > iCloud and uncheck all the options (on my Mac these were iCloud Drive, Desktop and Documents). Close preferences, reopen and recheck the same boxes. The files and folders reappeared in my finder.